# Gradescope failed to execute

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def fibs(n):
    count = 0
    val1 = 1
    val2 = 1
    while count != n:
       yield val1
       count += 1
       yield val2
       count += 1
       val1 += val2
       val2 += val1
    
def main():
    for curr in fibs(8):
       print(curr)
```

When I upload this to gradescope it is telling me that the autograder failed to execute correctly. Can anyone guess why this is happening ?

Comment: Try running your code on a different online sandbox like https://ideone.com/6S6WVN, and you'll see it has no output at all.

Comment: Hint: What actually _calls or starts your `main()` function_?

Comment: ...compare the above to, say, https://ideone.com/YRfkin

Comment: They say that nothing should be printed in the code in order to be graded correctly, therefore I did not put any calls to main().

Comment: What _exactly_ is the specification? That may have meant no logging info on stdout _except the output itself_.

Comment: Here is the exact error I get: ""The autograder failed to execute correctly. Please ensure that your submission is valid.""

Comment: I didn't ask for the error. I asked for the specification. Things like "nothing should be printed" is part of the specification your code is expected to comply with.

Comment: ""Implement a function def fibs(n). This function is given a positive integer n, and
returns a generator, that when iterated over, it will have the first n elements in the
Fibonacci sequence."'            a. Name all classes, functions and methods exactly as they are in the
assignment specifications.
b. Make sure there are no print statements in your code. If you have tester
code, please put it in a “main” function and do not call it.

Comment: "in the assignment specification" -- that's what I asked for. But yes, that _is_ explicit that it doesn't want main to be called. I still don't think this is an on-topic question -- something needs to be about a narrow, specific problem to be on-topic here, and if you don't _know_ what the specific problem is then we're stuck in the dark guessing as much as you -- but the current close reason is indeed clearly incorrect.

Comment: BTW, that kind of clarifying detail should be in the question itself, not just comments.